# Pandas/Sklearn: Indexing column and ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have written following script to find out the best features to be used in my sklearn algorithm.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
data = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
X = data.iloc[6:]  #columns with words
y = genre_to_binary(data.iloc[1])    #target column i.e genre
#apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
#concat two dataframes for better visualization 
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['Features','Genre']  #naming the dataframe columns
print(featureScores.nlargest(10,'Genre'))  #print 10 best features


data = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.feature_importances_) #use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers
#plot graph of feature importances for better visualization
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
def genre_to_binary(series):
    genres_list = series.values.tolist()
    converted_genre=[]
    for i in np.arange(len(genres_list)):
        if genres_list[i]=="action":
            converted_genre=np.append(converted_genre,0)
        else:
            converted_genre=np.append(converted_genre,1)
    return converted_genre
```

However, this throws following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-b772929399c8> in <module>
      1 #apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
      2 bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
----> 3 fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
      4 dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
      5 dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py in fit(self, X, y)
    339         self : object
    340         """
--> 341         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)
    342 
    343         if not callable(self.score_func):

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 719                     estimator=estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    534         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    535         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 536             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    537         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    538             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'natural born killers'
```

I do not understand why *natural born killers* is even contained in x or y since it only occurs in the column at index 0 which I do not access. So where is the problem?

You can find the file [here](https://tumde-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alexander_farr_tum_de/EauYmDrHzclOiKghjUqjZsQBHKjbJj-zdnWlH7fgA1BDjg?e=sWeZTC).

Comment: your input csv may have awkward inputs present, make sure it includes all fields for all rows

Comment: I think you saved the column name `'natural born killers'` as data in the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thank you but where did I save 'natural born killers' as data? It is just one value in the first column. And how do I find out whether the input is formatted in an awkward way?

Comment: @NikosM.@ccl could you help me?

Comment: @datasciencelearner, i'm not sure where the problem lies. I suspect the csv is corrupted. Try using another smaller csv than the original with some test values and test again. if it works the problem is in the input csv, else you will be better able to find the problem in the code